# Is the word "relative" an adverb?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Consider this example:

> The temperature rises *relative* to the other room.

The temperature rises *how*? It rises *slowly*, *occasionally*, *relative to the other room*. They all seem to answer the question *how*. Doesn't this mean that *relative* is also an *adverb* in this case? Both Wiktionary and Merriam-Webster suggest that it is only a noun and an adjective.

Comment: _relative to the other room_ functions adverbially, yes. But _relative_ on its own does not in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As oerkelens already commented the latter half of your sentence acts adverbially.

It is an [adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase).

Thus the word **relative** itself is not an adverb, the construction **relative to the other room** is an adverbial phrase, acting adverbially.